# If $\partial_1 f = \partial_2 f$ and $f(0,0) = 0$, $\exists g \in C(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x,y) = g(x,y) (x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that if $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$ and $\partial_1 f = \partial_2 f$ and $f(0,0) = 0$, there must be a $g \in C(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x,y) = g(x,y) (x+y)$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Clearly, if we define $g(x, y) := \frac{f(x,y)}{x + y} \; \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x \neq -y$, we will have a continuous function for all $(x,y)$ such that $x \neq -y$. In my opinion, it will be sufficient to prove that $L(x,y) := \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, -x_0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{x+y}$ exists, and then set $g (x) = L(x,y)$. However, I am stuck here.

I try to use the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiable. In particular, we have:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, -x_0)} \frac{f(x,y) - f(x_0,-x_0) - \partial({x_0, -x_0})\begin{bmatrix}
           x - x_0 \\
           y + x_0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}}{||\begin{bmatrix}
           x - x_0 \\
           y + x_0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}||} = 0
\end{equation}
I see that $f(x,-x) = 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\partial_1(x,y) = \partial_2(x,y)$, so I get:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, -x_0)} \frac{f(x,y) - \partial_1({x_0, -x_0}) \cdot (x + y)}{||\begin{bmatrix}
           x - x_0 \\
           y + x_0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}||} = 0
\end{equation}

However, I cannot see how I could use it to show that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, -x_0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{x + y}
\end{equation}
exists.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have (using first $f(0,0)=0$ in the first step, then fundamental theorem of calculus in the second step and finally $\partial_1 f = \partial_2 f$ in the last step)
$$ f(x,y) = f(x,y) - f(0,0) = \int_0^1 \left[ \frac{d}{dt} f(tx, ty) \right] dt
= \int_0^1 \left[ (\partial_1 f)(tx,ty) \cdot x + (\partial_2 f)(tx,ty) \cdot y \right] dt = \int_0^1 (\partial_1 f)(tx,ty) dt \cdot (x+y). $$
I leave it to you to show that $g(x,y) = \int_0^1 (\partial_1 f)(tx,ty) dt$ is continuous (Hint: continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous).

Comment: I think this is such a wonderful argument. +1

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you so much!